# In Node.JS 10.15.3, "ẞ".toLowerCase() returns "Ṿ"

Tags: node.js, unicode

I tried to find information regarding this issue online, to resolve whether updating Node.JS can help with this issue before, to no avail.

In Node 10.15.3, case-converting `capital letter Eszett` to lower case yields the `capital letter V with dot below` instead of the lower case `eszett`.

```js
console.log("ẞ".toLowerCase()); // "Ṿ"
```

Can anyone with newer Node verify whether this is still an issue? Browsers I tested get this right.

(I *could* just download Node and try myself, but I wanted to leave a mark for posteriority, *and* I’m lazy).

Comment: The current LTS is Node 12, not Node 10, so you probably want to upgrade to the latest long-term-support version and see if your bug still exists there. No point in trying to figure out why an out of date (but technically under support) version of Node is misbehaving? Having said that, if that's not an option: have you filed an issue for this, first? If not: please do that now. You're asking about open source behaviour, and open source does not improve when people only ask questions on SO without making sure the folks who maintain that open source software are aware of issues =)

Comment: As for "people with newer node": that's you. Install https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm or https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows if you're on Windows, and test it. If you're using Node, `nvm` and `npx` are the two utilities you kind of need to always have installed globally (and, with those installed, _nothing else_ needs to be installed globally)

Comment: @"Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans" **Current** Node is Node 13. https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/ Node 10 and Node 12 are currently both **Active** Node versions. 10 will be Out of date on 2021-04-30. I will look into submitting an issue, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I too know how to [read a roadmap](https://github.com/nodejs/Release). While they're both "active", 12 is the current LTS version, and 10 is the previous LTS version. 10 might go out of any kind of support in 2021, but it goes out of _development_ in 3 months, so you want to start upgrading now if you can. Node moves fast, and keeping up with versions is a constant task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, okay, alright, the issue is no longer present on Node 13.8.0.

```
console.log("ß".toUpperCase()); // SS
console.log("ẞ".toLowerCase()); // ß
```